# Cálculo de Tabela de Frete

Tags: php, codeigniter

tenho a seguinte tabela de frete

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tenho a seguinte tabela de bairro

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Onde na tabelafrete -> idSaida = 1 = Centro e idDestino = 2 = Abranches
Neste caso um produto será coletado no Centro e entregue no Abranches.
Este serviço foi feito de moto - pontoMoto
Se somarmos o resultado será 2 pontos.

O problema é que não estou conseguindo desenvolver o cálculo dessa pontuação. 
Alguém aqui já desenvolveu algo semelhante? Tem alguma idéia?

Produzindo um teste, o primeiro resultado do print_r($dados):

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [tiposervico] => 0
        [endereco] => asdfasdf
        [numero] => 
        [bairro] => 1
        [cidade] => Curitiba
        [falarcom] => 
        [idChamada] => 34
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [tiposervico] => 1
        [endereco] => afsdf adf asf
        [numero] => 
        [bairro] => 2
        [cidade] => Curitiba
        [falarcom] => 
        [idChamada] => 34
    )
```

Tentei fazer da seguinte forma, ao inserir os serviços...

```
public function addChamadaServico($dados)
{


    $campo['idSaida'] = $dados[0]['bairro'];
    $campo['idDestino'] = $dados[1]['bairro'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tabelafrete WHERE idSaida = ".$campo['idSaida']." AND idDestino = ".$campo['idDestino']."";
    $consulta = $this->db->query($sql)->result();

    //echo $sql;

    foreach($consulta as $valor){
        $contagem = $valor->pontoMoto * 15;
        echo $contagem; 
    }
```

}

Até ai, aparentemente funciona... mas o caso é que pode ter vários "destinos" em bairros diferentes e um retorno, ou vários retornos em bairros diferentes... alguém tem alguma ideia?